# Embed Python CLI in a Ruby process?

Tags: python, ruby, subprocess, pipe, interactive

As part of a larger project, I'm trying to "embed" a Python interactive interpreter in a Ruby process. I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> pipe = IO.popen("python", "w+")
=> #<IO:0x7f3dba4977e0>
irb(main):002:0> pipe.puts "print 'hello'"
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> pipe.gets
=> 'hello\n'
```

Unfortunately, the `gets` seems to hang rather than return any kind of output from the Python process. I've tried variations of this procedure with `open3`, using mode `r+` instead of `w+`, and a couple other minor options (`python -u` among them), with no success.

Is there a way to establish interactive communication with a Python shell from Ruby - in effect, to "wrap" the Python CLI? I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) and Python 2.6.6 on an x86_64 machine, though hopefully solutions will be portable(ish) across Python versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`popen` doesn't look like a terminal to python, so you are not running in interactive mode.  You can force python to start in interactive mode with `-i`:

```
IO.popen("python -i", "r+") do |py|
  while cmd = gets
    py.puts cmd
    puts py.gets
  end
end
```

You'll probably have to do some work to remove the `>>>` prompt, etc.

**EDIT**: here is the multi-line friendly version (I'm preserving the code is clear and answered the original question):

```
IO.popen("python -i", "r+") do |py|
  loop do
    fds = IO.select [py, STDIN]
    fds.each do |(fd)|
      case fd
      when nil;    next
      when STDIN;  py.puts gets
      else;        puts py.gets
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if there are multiple lines on the output. Try to run print 'line1\nline2'. It returns only line1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach using Ruby's pseudo-terminal library. I've tested this with ruby 1.9 on Linux and MacOS X, it won't probably run on Windows:

```
require 'pty'

begin
  # stty -echo turns off terminal echo, without it tty input would be repeated
  # on output
  PTY.spawn( "stty -echo; python" ) do |r, w, pid|
    begin

      cmd = nil
      begin
        w.puts cmd if cmd != nil

        # non-blocking read of stdout with 2 seconds timeout
        while IO.select([r], nil, nil, 2)
          print r.getc
        end

      end while cmd = gets

    rescue Errno::EIO
      puts "end of output"
    end
  end
rescue PTY::ChildExited => e
  puts "The child process exited."
end
```